# Azure Function with Event Hub trigger receives weird amount of events

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I have an Event Hub and Azure Function connected to it. With small amounts of data all works well, but when I tested it with 10 000 events, I got very peculiar results.
For test purposes I send into Event hub numbers from 0 to 9999 and log data in application insights and in service bus. For the first test I see in Azure that hub got exactly 10 000 events, but service bus and AI got all messages between 0 and 4500, and every second message after 4500 (so it lost about 30%). In second test, I got all messages from 0 to 9999, but every second message between 3500 and 3200 was duplicated. I would like to get all messages once, what did I do wrong?

```
public async Task Run([EventHubTrigger("%EventHubName%", Connection = "AzureEventHubConnectionString")] EventData[] events, ILogger log)
    {
        int id = _random.Next(1, 100000);
        _context.Log.TraceInfo("Started. Count: " + events.Length + ". " + id); //AI log
        foreach (var message in events)
        {
            //log with ASB
            var mess = new Message();
            mess.Body = message.EventBody.ToArray();
            await queueClient.SendAsync(mess);
        }
        _context.Log.TraceInfo("Completed. " + id); //AI log
    }
```

Comment: have you sampling enabled in AI?

Comment: no, I disabled sampling

Answer (score 2):

By using EventData[] events, you are reading events from hub in batch mode, thats why you see X events processing at a time then next seconds you process next batch.

Instead of EventData[] use simply **EventData**.

When you send events to hub check that all events are sent with the same partition key if you want try batch processing otherwise they can be splitted in several partitions depending on TU (throughput units), PU (Processing Units) and CU (Capacity Units).

Egress: Up to 2 MB per second or 4096 events per second.

[Refer to this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-scalability).

Throughput limits for Basic, Standard, Premium..:

[image]

Comment: thanks for answering! yes, I know that I read in batches, function usually processes 10 events per execution, but this code is supposed to log every single message between 0 and 9999 to service bus (10 000 messages in total), right ? but I get approximately 7500 messages in service bus, or 10150 sometimes. Looks like some messages get lost or doubled at some point and I don't understand how and where..

Comment: No, you are reading X events depending on Hub partition. Updated answer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm totally new to AF and Event Hubs, so I might be doing something wrong, but now I logged in AI partitionKey for each event, and I do see that they have different partition keys, and I got 9550 lines instead of 10 000. So I do log different partitions, but I am not able to find the missing 450 events. I tried also to process simply EventData, not a batch, and got this message in Azure: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs: Binding to individual events is not supported. Please use batch processing by binding to an array instead.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-output?tabs=csharp Review your nugets maybe? Anyways it will slow down your processing. How are you sending events to your event hub?

Comment: I've made a dotnet console app for sending test data into event hub. It seems to work, I get exactly 10k in event hub in Azure: for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                {
                    using EventDataBatch eventBatch = await producerClient.CreateBatchAsync();
                    string test = "{test: 4, id: " + i + "}";
                    eventBatch.TryAdd(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(test)));
                    await producerClient.SendAsync(eventBatch);
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                }

Comment: SendBatchAsync(EventData, (string)partitionKey) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.eventhubs.eventhubclient.sendasync?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: Add a Delay in your test before send 1k events.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things likely happening, though I can only speculate with the limited context that we have.   Knowing more about the testing methodology, tier of your Event Hubs namespace, and the number of partitions in your Event Hub would help.

The first thing to be aware of is that the timing between when an event is published and when it is available in a partition to be read is non-deterministic.  When a publish operation completes, the Event Hubs broker has acknowledged receipt of the events and taken responsibility for ensuring they are persisted to multiple replicas and made available in a specific partition. However, it is not a guarantee that the event can immediately be read.

Depending on how you sent the events, the broker may also need to route events from a gateway by performing a round-robin or applying a hash algorithm.  If you're looking to optimize the time from publish to availability, taking ownership of partition distribution and publishing directly to a partition can help, as can ensuring that you're publishing with the right degree of concurrency for your host environment and scenario.

With respect to duplication, it's important to be aware that Event Hubs offers an "at least once" guarantee; your consuming application should expect some duplicates and needs to be able to handle them in the way that is appropriate for your application scenario.

Azure Functions uses a set of event processors in its infrastructure to read events.  The processors collaborate with one another to share work and distribute the responsibility for partitions between them.  Because collaboration takes place using storage as an intermediary to synchronize, there is an overlap of partition ownership when instances are scaled up or scaled down, during which time the potential for duplication is increased.

Functions makes the decision to scale based on the number of events that it sees waiting in partitions to be read.  In the case of your test, if your publication pattern increases rapidly and Functions sees "the event backlog" grow to the point that it feels the need to scale by multiple instances, you'll see more duplication than you otherwise would for a period of 10-30 seconds until partition ownership normalizes.  To mitigate this, using an approach of gradually increasing speed of publishing over a 1-2 minute period can help to smooth out the scaling and reduce (but not eliminate) duplication.

Comment: Depending on the tier of your namespace, there are also quotas involved for ingress/egress data that can result in throttling, we'll gloss over them for now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have basic pricing tier and partition count is 2. I logged partition key to AI and I actually see many different keys being logged. I understand now why I get duplicates, but why do I loose data?

Comment: I'm not sure that you are losing data;  you haven't shown us a snippet for how you're publishing, so its difficult to speculate.  Basic has a lower quota and is likely to throttle more.  Sending 10,000 messages will definitely take a bit, and the large volume of data going to the gateway for processing the partition key and then routing to a partition will also take some time.   It may be that your publishing is taking longer than you think, or there may be something else at play.  I'd suggest updating the question to demonstrate your publishing flow and tell us more about how you're testing.

Comment: I've made a simple dotnet console app for sending test data into event hub. It seems to work, I get exactly 10k in event hub in Azure: for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) { using EventDataBatch eventBatch = await producerClient.CreateBatchAsync(); string test = "{test: 4, id: " + i + "}"; eventBatch.TryAdd(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(test))); await producerClient.SendAsync(eventBatch); Console.WriteLine(i); } and I wait long time to be sure that Azure Function stopped working and usually it processes about 7000-8000 messages out of 10 000.

Comment: I also have a console app getting data from event hub and sending it to service bus, and it seems to work correct. I get exactly 10 000 messages in service bus. I use same code in AF and in this app (except for offset handling, in console app I same the offset to blob), so I feel like the problem is in EventHubTrigger...

Comment: I don't see anything obvious in the producer code, and if you're seeing the expected count come back in a console application, that would seem to indicate that the events are available to be read.   I don't have more than superficial knowledge of how the bindings work with the SDK, so I can't do much beyond speculate without much basis.   From the code snippet, it appears that you're using the beta bindings;  would you mind opening an issue in the [SDK repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues) so that I can pull in the folks working on those bindings to assist?